# purchase errors via 2accounts

Tags: in-app-purchase, simulator

My gmail make purchase outside 2 accounts
But if I used it with app inside 2 accounts gives me that error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZt1r.jpg)how can I solve it

Tru to make purchase but failes
How can I make successful purchase using google play store via 2 accounts